# How to install torchtext 0.4.0 on conda

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, torchtext

The torchtext 0.4.0 library exists (can be downloaded thru pip), but `conda install torchtext=0.4.0` will not work. How can I download torchtext to a anaconda environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create conda env with python:

   $ conda create -n torchtext python=3.7
2. Activate it:

   $ conda activate torchtext

`torchtext 0.4.0` installation currently is not available via `conda`. So we will use `pip`, anyway `pip` installs `torchtext` inside your activated `conda` env.

3. Let's find `torchtex` available versions:

   (torchtext)$ pip search torchtext
   torchtext (0.3.1) - Text utilities and datasets for PyTorch

As you can see there is no `0.4.0`. 
4. But we can install it from official github repo:

```
(torchtext)$ pip install git+https://github.com/pytorch/text.git
```

5. Verify the installation:

   (torchtext)$ conda list

   ...

   torch                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi

   torchtext            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi

   tqdm                 4.32.2                   pypi_0    pypi

   ...

   (torchtext)$ python -c "import torchtext; print('torchtext is fine!')"

   torchtext is fine!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the pytorch channel as described on the official anaconda site:

```
conda install -c pytorch torchtext
```

https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchtext

Answer (score 0):

```sh
conda install -c derickl torchtext
```

torchtext package is available in derickl channel. You can also use pip install in conda. The conda environment will create a layer of pip installed packages.

Comment: This gives torchtext 0.3.0, though.

Comment: It should be there `conda list`. If you do `conda env export > environment.yml` and open the yaml file, you will see under pip, the packages that conda will install using pip when recreation environment from y’all file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install  `torchtext-0.4.0` in my windows's anaconda environment using

`pip install https://github.com/pytorch/text/archive/master.zip`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding it to [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html), there was a good start [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/8260/commits/f80f179713f835aa591b65d80bc465e4a3e1d3f0) but I don't think it went into conda-forge. Then you could run `conda install -c conda-forge torchtext`